# Why do objects changed in function change what they point to in memory, but sometimes create a new memory object?

Tags: javascript

I was reading on [this blog](http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2013/06/a-look-into-how-parameters-are-passed.html) about how if an object or array were changed inside of a function, the value in memory that was pointed to would be changed as well, the same as if it were changed outside the function.

```
var a = [1,2,3],
    b = a;

b[0] = 5;
console.log(a); // [5, 2, 3]
```

would result in the same as

```
var a = [1,2,3],
    b = a;

var arrayFunction = function(arr){
   arr[0] = 10;
};

var arr = arrayFunction(b);

console.log(a, b, arr) // [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3];
```

Yet what I can't understand is why reassigning multiple array values within the function does not change the values outside of it:

```
var a = [1,2,3],
    b = a;

var arrayFunction = function(arr){
   arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
   return arr;
};

var result = arrayFunction(b);
console.log(result) //["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(a, b);  //[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]
```

Why does this not change the pointed to value in memory like in the first example?

Probably a better job of writing out the examples on [the JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/agadix/2/edit)

Comment: this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that, within the function, `arr` is not the actual array; `arr` is a reference that points to the array.

So when you say `arr[0]`, you're retrieving the array, and then getting or updating an item in it.

But when you say `arr = ["a","b","c"]`, you are creating a new object (on the right side) and then turning `arr` into a reference that points to the new object.

Comment: oh. Obviously! ugh. This makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 3):

This is because objects in javascript aren't **really** passed by reference. I've seen it referred to as "passed by copied reference", or "passed by handle" - both of which do a better job of describing what's really happening.

In this example:

```
var b = [1, 2, 3];
var arrayFunction = function(arr) {
   arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
};
arrayFunction(b);
```

The object reference itself is passed by value. You're not actually changing the value of the `b` variable. However, your function argument (`arr`) and the `b` variable are initially pointing to the same object - so if you change one, you can reference the object through either and see the change.

When you reassign `arr` to point to a different object though, the `b` variable is still pointing to the old object, and does not change.

Comment: yes. absolutely. Thanks a million. For some reason that just didn't click with me.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript a variable merely **points** to an array; so if you copy the variable you get two variables pointing to the same array:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = a;
```

Changing an element of the array with `a[0] = 99` will be observable with both variables because there is just one array and both `a` and `b` are pointing to it.

When you write instead

```
a = [5, 6, 7];
```

you are setting `a` to point to another different array.

Javascript never makes a copy of an array unless you ask it explicitly (e.g. with `b = a.slice()`).

Actually the very same happens with any value (objects for example). With numbers and string  the same logic is also valid, but it's hard to notice the difference between a copy and sharing the same object because numbers and strings cannot be changed (the're "immutable").

In other languages like C and C++ instead variables contain the value, not a pointer; so when making an assignment for example objects are copied from one variable to the other and if you want a pointer you've to ask explicitly for it.